# Java send to EventHub (not shutting down gracefully)

Tags: java, azure, gradle, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send alot of data from a server over to my event hub, however when I try to use the example code from microsoft doc the data is being sent but the application never stop running. I fill up my arraylist with 100 data at a time then I run the method.

```
    public static void publishEvents(List<EventData> allEvents) {
        // create a producer client
        EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
            .buildProducerClient();

       

        // create a batch
        EventDataBatch eventDataBatch = producer.createBatch();

        for (EventData eventData : allEvents) {
            // try to add the event from the array to the batch
            if (!eventDataBatch.tryAdd(eventData)) {
                // if the batch is full, send it and then create a new batch
                producer.send(eventDataBatch);
                eventDataBatch = producer.createBatch();

                // Try to add that event that couldn't fit before.
                if (!eventDataBatch.tryAdd(eventData)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event is too large for an empty batch. Max size: "
                        + eventDataBatch.getMaxSizeInBytes());
                }
            }
        }
        // send the last batch of remaining events
        if (eventDataBatch.getCount() > 0) {
            producer.send(eventDataBatch);
        }
        producer.close();
    }
```

I tried using an async approach which seems to work fine but creating a new connection for each data to be sent seems like a bad idea and when using this for sending alot of data.

```
        EventHubProducerAsyncClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .buildAsyncProducerClient();

        // Create a batch and add a sample log to it
        producer.createBatch().flatMap(batch ->
        {
            batch.tryAdd(new EventData(event));


            return producer.send(batch);
        }).subscribe(unused -> {
                },
                error -> System.err.println("Couldn't send logs, there's an error: " + error.getStackTrace()),
                () ->
                {
                    System.out.println("Send complete!");
                    // Close the connection
                    producer.close();
                });

    }
```

Would need some help to fix the problem where the application never exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be related to the bug here where we do not dispose of a resource to allow this to close properly. Your repro looks like this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/22305

For the asynchronous code, the `.subscribe()` call just sets up the subscription and invokes the call before moving to the next line of code. (It's a non-blocking call.) If your main method looked like the one below, the program would have probably ended before it had time to create an AMQP connection/session/link to the Event Hub. So that would be why the program ended gracefully.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventHubProducerAsyncClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString)
            .buildAsyncProducerClient();

    // Create a batch and add a sample log to it
    producer.createBatch().flatMap(batch -> {
        batch.tryAdd(new EventData(event));
        return producer.send(batch);
    }).subscribe(unused -> {
        },
        error -> System.err.println("Couldn't send logs, there's an error: " + error.getStackTrace()),
        () -> {
            System.out.println("Send complete!");
            // Close the connection
            producer.close();
        });
}
```